# windows server advanced firewall not immediately apply changes to rule scope updated from powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-firewall

I have a scheduled task which extract ip address from the list of failed login attempt on a sql machine, and update a firewall rule with something like this:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="BlockIpFromSQLFailedLogin" new remoteip="192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3" action="block"
```

**But it does not immediately have effect.** After a while the firewall seems to reload it's configuration and finally starts blocking access for the new added ip addresses.

How can I force the firewall to immediately refresh and start blocking them?

I can see a similar behavior from the UI of windows advanced firewall, because after running the script if I open the rule and open the scope I can see the old list of ip address. If I click "refresh" the list is updated and the ip are blocked.

I can't seem to find how to force the firewall to refresh from a powershell script.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: I seem to recall that Windows FW only looks at the config file every 5 minutes or so, so this is consistent with that. Can you not just disable/enable the fw to force?

Comment: @Scepticalist but how can I do that programmatically from powershell?